# VideoView uri change,loading again

Tags: android

When `VideoView URI` is getting changed,i hope that `mVideoView` can reload,what should i do? `VideoView` method is:

```
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoViewUri));
    if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
        mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        if (isWifi()) {
            mVideoView.start();
        }
        Log.i("quickshare_isshow", "heheheheheh");
    } else {
        if (isWifi()) {
            mVideoView.start();
            Log.i("uri", videoViewUri);
        }
    }
```